# Puppeteer run javascript in website console (devtools)

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

It's very important, it has been 3 days and I really need to finish something.
I want to run something in the devtools console of a website with a node.js code, could anyone help me? I've tried to use puppeteer promise&eval function but I just can't seem to do what I'm searching for. 
 
This is my code after I run chromium and open the website I want to go to.

````
console.log(await page.evaluate(
    function login(token) {
    setInterval(() => {
    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement `iframe`).contentWindow.localStorage.token = `"${token}"`
    }, 50);
    setTimeout(() => {
    location.reload();
    }, 2500);
    }
));

page.waitFor( 2000 ).then(console.log('Next command'))

var account = "";

console.log(await page.evaluate(
    account = `myaccount`
));


page.waitFor( 2000 ).then(console.log('Next command'))

console.log(await page.evaluate(
    login(account)```
````

Comment: elaborate on what you're trying to achieve and the problems you're having.

Comment: Hello @mbit . So I'm trying to run the commands listed up from the ''page.evaluate" into the website devtools console.
The code will make a function login(token) and when you run it, it will add in localStorage of the current window that token.

Comment: EDIT: It won't add the token, it'll make a key called token with the value I set up in second command. ----------------------------

I've did the function, and it worked, but there's was problem, I can't use `var` and `login` in the page.evaluate(), I could only add the ''token'' manually via ''var token = "token"; then login(token);

The second problem is that I want to include the function listed up with the timeouts and the interval, because when I did it I only managed to include it via document.body.appendChild.

Comment: UPDATE: I actually need to know mostly how to create a function that I can run on the website.

Comment: I wrote an answer, let me know if that doesn't address your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a function with `addScriptTag`:

```js
await page.setBypassCSP(true);
await page.goto("https://example.com");
function login(token) {
    setInterval(() => {
        document.body.appendChild(document.createElement `iframe`).contentWindow.localStorage.token = token;
    }, 50);
    setTimeout(() => {
        location.reload();
    }, 2500);
}
await page.addScriptTag({content: `${login}`})
```

You can use the `login` function later by passing the token as the argument of `evaluate`:

```js
myToken = "12345";
await page.evaluate(t => login(t), myToken)
```

Comment: Thanks. It does what I asked for it to do, i'll check around to see if I can make it work on the live version of chromium

Comment: Checked. Dude, you're a life saver and a god. I searched about this for 1 week, I owe you mate! Thank you so much!